# Using a background image with Twilio's programmable video

Tags: image, video, background, twilio

Is it possible to display a background image when doing a video conference with Twilio's programmable video? We want the customer to see our technicians but we want to display a custom background.

If this is possible, how is it done?

I can not find any info on how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can change your background in a Twilio Video call with the [Twilio Video Processors Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/video-processors)!

Here is a [tutorial detailing how to do so from my colleague Miguel Grinberg](https://www.twilio.com/blog/change-background-video-calls-twilio-video-processors-library).

Virtual backgrounds are currently available in the Chrome and Edge browsers.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Is it possible to add my own images to the background? to upload an image and to use it?

Comment: You can add your own image as shown in the blog post by Miguel above under the `Replacing the background` header

Comment: Video Processors run at very low rate if tab is in background or if background if applied on twilio room. Framerate sometimes even drops to 0.

Comment: Hello, we're trying to use the sample code from Miguel, but as soon as the code that adds the background is executed, the small preview picture goes all black - no more video. Is this a known issue?